# AWS elastic beanstalk eb init command Mumbai region not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

When I am running `eb init` command all zones are available except Mumbai region. My EB CLI version is 3.7.3. Any idea?[image: EB CLI screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Version 3.7.3 of the EB CLI was released on 2016 January 28.

The Mumbai `ap-south-1` region was [added as an AWS Region on 2016 June 27](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-open-aws-asia-pacific-mumbai-region/).

To see this region, simply update to the [latest version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awsebcli/3.7.8) of EB CLI and try again. The changelog specifically notes that this region was added in version 3.7.7, so that or any later version should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For posteriety's sake, if you do not wish to upgrade, you can also get around this problem by executing:

```
eb init --region ap-south-1
```